# Android Widget that can start/stop a service and receive updates every second

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-sensors

I need to create an Android Widget that basically has just a Start/Stop Button and a Field with some information. The Start button should start a service that gets a result every second or so. One part of this result should be displayed in the Widget and the service can be stopped again by pushing the stop button.

Can anyone point me please into the right direction how the strategy to implement this would be?

I've read a lot now, but I am really unsure. From what I understand an AlarmManager would be overkill and drain the Battery really fast or make the phone unresponsive. Also I cant use a BroadcastReceiver since the Service takes more than 5 secs (?? not sure about this).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is advisable that while creating the service from widget you should stop it as soon as you do the necessary changes you require as the running service would use battery and memory.

For making widget this would be helpful:-

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        //Give the name of service you want to start in your case Alarm Service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        //This basically sets the layout of your widget to widget_layout
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
```

For your service class you could use stopSelf() in OnStart() methood after doing the changes you require.